# Как запустить что-то внутри docker-контейнера с приложением?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Развернул окружение для сайта через `docker-compose`. 
Сайт на **laravel** и ему требуется выполнить `composer install`, но выполнение данной команды говорит что у меня старая версия **php**.
Получается, что нужно и **composer** устанавливать в контейнер? Может есть другие решения?

Файл docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: evild/alpine-nginx:1.9.15-openssl
    container_name: lemp_nginx
    restart: always
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/
      - ./docker/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443
  php:
    image: evild/alpine-php:7.0.6
    working_dir: /var/www
    container_name: lemp_php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/
    depends_on:
      - db

    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=mysql
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: lemp_mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password


volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
```

Comment: а как вы запускаете `composer`?

Comment: я его запускаю вне контейнера

Comment: я так понимаю что его нужно запускать внутри контейнера, но внутри php контейнера у меня нет composer

Comment: вы правильно понимаете. можете считать, что контейнер это другой компьютер (виртуальная машина).

Comment: скаж те как это сделать? нужно устанавливать отдельный контейнер для composer или его можно запустить внутри php контейнера, используя composer установленный локально

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: А что именно дополнить? По моему в вопросе понятно
Как запустить composer внутри контейнера с приложением

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается это так:

1. Определить имя или id контейнера

   ```
   docker ps
   ```
2. Войти в контейнер. shell - это обычно bash.

   ```
   docker exec -it <имя или id контейнера> <shell>
   ```
3. Внутри контейнера выполнить нужные вам команды. В вашем случае установить `composer`

   ```
   php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
   php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55d6ead61b29c7bdee5cccfb50076874187bd9f21f65d8991d46ec5cc90518f447387fb9f76ebae1fbbacf329e583e30') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
   php composer-setup.php
   php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
   ```

**NB**

Эти изменения пропадут после перезапуска контейнера. Если вы хотите, что бы они остались, то вам нужно создать новую версию контейнера и использовать ее в `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Опишите пжл второй вариант, нужно чтобы composer установился один раз и команду можно было запускать всегда

Comment: задайте новый вопрос и приложите к нему Dockerfile.

Comment: извините но я делитант в вопросаx docker, что за dockefile - вы имели ввиду docker-compose.yml?

Comment: приложите docker-compose.yml и я скажу, что еще надо преложить.

Comment: добавил описание файла

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620945/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-composer-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-docker