# Как установить composer в отдельный контейнер docker

Tags: docker, composer, docker-compose

Есть файл docker-copmose.yml 
Необходимо установить контейнер copmoser для корректноого разворачивания приложения
Как это можно сделать?

**Описание docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: evild/alpine-nginx:1.9.15-openssl
    container_name: lemp_nginx
    restart: always
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/
      - ./docker/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443
  php:
    image: evild/alpine-php:7.0.6
    working_dir: /var/www
    container_name: lemp_php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/
    depends_on:
      - db

    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_NAME=mysql
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: lemp_mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password


volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете файл `Dockerfile` со следующим содержимым

```
FROM evild/alpine-php:7.0.6

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55d6ead61b29c7bdee5cccfb50076874187bd9f21f65d8991d46ec5cc90518f447387fb9f76ebae1fbbacf329e583e30') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Изменяете ваш `docker-compose.yml`. Вместо `image: evild/alpine-php:7.0.6` прописываете `build: .`

Comment: опишите пжл дальнейшие действия

Comment: Сделал как вы описали, захожу в контейнер php, затем ввожу composer install -> команда не найдена

Comment: @ruslik как вы заходите в контейнер?

Comment: docker exec -it lemp_mariadb sh

Comment: Причем при первой установке мне выдало сообщение что composer установился в var/www/html, но у меня нет такой папки в контейнере

Comment: попробуйте `php composer.phar`

Comment: Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: а какие файлы там есть? покажите `ls -la`

Comment: Там много файлов, какая именно директория интересует /var/www это?

Comment: я обновил Dockerfile. теперь `composer` должен быть доступен.